# display images in the center of the page side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have the following code, that loads me all image paths from the database:

```
    <% sweet.forEach(function (item) { %>
    "img id="pictureproduct" src="<%= item.picture%>"/>
    <% }); %>
```

I tried everything I know to make the images load as follows:

- The images should load in the center of the page
- The images should be side by side
- Only 4 or 5 images should load on one line side by side

Can you help me do this somehow with CSS?

Comment: Float them in a centered container. Use flexbox.

Comment: Welcome to [so], Flaviu. Ref: *i tried everything i know...*. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/299/centering#t=20170418194459491508) and you will know more. You should also consider creating a [mcve], that would enables us to see what you have so far, how the final `html` markup looks like and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Put your images in a flex container (flexbox). Create a div `<div class="images-parent">` and put your images in:

```
.images-parent{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
}
```

Comment: You should refrain from answering questions that do not show any research effort. You are encouraging OP and other users to ask more low quality questions. Please see [answer] for details.

Comment: But i did not find this question Off topic. The explanations is enough and clear, and your link is for centering one element, maybe he can not use that for multiple elements centering.

Comment: First of all, I didn't say it's off-topic. Second, as a rule of thumb, whenever you have to make assumptions in order to answer it, the question is low quality. In this case, how can you provide `CSS` when you don't know how the markup looks like?

Comment: *whenever you have to make assumptions in order to answer it, the question is off topic.* It is interesting, but there is no clear law for this. We have seen many questions without any code that have more than 100 upvoats.

Comment: Regarding the link I provided in the comment under the question, take your time to read all the techniques listed there, it might help. That's [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation), it's not some random question/answer. It's a beta feature in which a lot of experienced users have hand-picked best answers in order to make [so] even more useful than it already is.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
.images-parent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.images-parent img {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 .5em;
}
```

if you want to change the height of the images you have to change the margin-top too.

Comment: Absolute positioning seems like a bad solution, along with all the specific values that need to be set. This can be done without being so stringent.

Comment: @hungerstar there is nothing wrong with absolute positioning, specific values are best choice for supporting old browsers. If you dont care about old browsers you always can use transform. No need to down voting.